# After delete from sqlite DB have a blank row

Tags: java, android, sqlite

After delete from sqlite DB have blank row, and the next data record to the next row after empty. How to fix this problem? Before i delete some thin all works correctly, but after deleting i have this problem.

```
private static final String DB_CREATE = 
        "create table " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                COLUMN_NAME + " text, " +
                COLUMN_TIME + " text, " +
                COLUMN_RAW_TIME + " integer " +
                ");";
```

for deleting i use:

```
//method which called delRec from DB class
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        db.delRec(acmi.id);
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
    }
    else if (item.getItemId() ==  RESET_STOPWATCH){
        AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        db.resetTime(Long.toString(acmi.id));
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}




// delete
public void delRec(long id) {
    //mDB.delete(DB_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + id, null);
    mDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM mytab WHERE _id = " + id);

}
```

for adding:

```
public void addRec(String txt, String txt2, long time) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_TIME, txt2);
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, txt );
    cv.put(COLUMN_RAW_TIME, time );
    mDB.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Comment: Consider adding some details to the question, such as code.

Comment: Write your code exactly what you want to delete and what blank row you got.

Comment: Some code, good. Please add your table scheme (the `CREATE TABLE`) and explain what you mean with an empty/blank row.

Comment: for example: I have 4 el in my db, i delete one row, after that, i insert new data, but, id of row, which adding is 5, not 4, that is problem

Comment: may be mistake is in list adapter?

Answer (score 0):

The `autoincrement` makes the generated row ids unique. The same id won't be generated again.

If you want to generate ids as `MAX(id)+1` with possible id reuse, remove the `autoincrement` and keep the `primary key`. If you want to reuse any available id number in the middle, you'll have to find it first.

Other than that, reconsider your approach. Missing id numbers in the middle should not be a problem. The problem is in the code where you display your data, not in the data itself.